# Solr: manipulate query string

Tags: solr, lucene, search-engine, sql-execution-plan

How can I manipulate query strings that are sent to Solr?

For example, someone enters "stackoverflow-version1.0" but there will be no results found. However if the query was only "stackoverflow" the search would have been successful.
So I want to truncate at "-" and search again for the first part.

Some research brought me to the *solr.PatternReplaceCharFilterFactory* class. I included it as shown below in my schema.xml. Does anyone see, why my query still does not yield any results? Any other classes I should use?

UPDATE:
Now my code looks like follows:

```
<fieldType name="ngram" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.NGramTokenizerFactory" minGramSize="1" maxGramSize="20" />
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
      generateWordParts="1"
      splitOnNumerics="0"
      generateNumberParts="0"
      catenateWords="0"
      catenateNumbers="0"
      catenateAll="0"
      preserveOriginal="1"
    />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
      generateWordParts="1"
      generateNumberParts="0"
      splitOnNumerics="0"
      catenateWords="0"
      catenateNumbers="0"
      catenateAll="0"
      preserveOriginal="1"
    />
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

Running the analyzer it gives me this:
[image]

And here the query UI:[image]

Comment: Could you clarify, is the failing query: `stackoverflow-version1.0` or `"stackoverflow-version1.0"`

Comment: It is the first one without the quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the **WordDelimiterFilterFactory** , it has many option that can be tried ...

You can try the below field type for your field.

```
<fieldtype name="subword" class="solr.TextField">
      <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="0"
                catenateNumbers="0"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
      <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1"
                generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1"
                catenateNumbers="1"
                catenateAll="0"
                preserveOriginal="1"
                />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
          <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"/>
      </analyzer>
    </fieldtype>
```

Here you can play around with the **WordDelimiterFilterFactory**

Once the FieldType is added and applied to the field.

Restart the server and you can analyse the input and output in the solr analysis page. On the solr analysis page it will show you how the token are generated for the input given at the time of index and query.

This will help you to build your own custom field type as per your requirement.

Here is link which list out all the tokenizers and filters with example.
[analyzers](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory)

Comment: I updated my code as shown above but still, I cannot find "stackoverflow" when I enter "stackoverflow-version1.0"

Comment: Did you check the tokens created in solr admin page...?what all tokens are created in index and what all tokens are created for query...? Could you post the same here...? It would be helpful to guide you ...

Comment: I added a screenshot. Does this part say enough? Because the output was much bigger actually

Comment: But its shows that your query is getting the result. You can see the highlighted part indicates the same. It indicates that you are getting the results. Now whats the problem you are facing?

Comment: making the same query on the query page it says:  "response": {
    "numFound": 0,
    "start": 0,
    "docs": []

Comment: ok..check if are missing the core/collection name... or may be you need to restart the server after you have done the changes to schema.xml and then re-index the data again...

Comment: I checked the url, restarted the server and re-indexed the data but still if gives me zero results ...

Comment: can you fire the same query using the solr admin UI and check the response ...along with it can you again analyse the same query in the solr analysis page

Comment: can you try by changing splitOnNumerics=1 in both query and index in your fieldType...here you have to again restart the server and re-index the data